# Why does adding StructLayout attribute to a WCF MessageContract cause the type to not load?

Tags: .net, wcf

I'm running into an issue adding a StructLayout attribute to a MessageContract class, for example:

```
[MessageContract(...)]
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public class Foo { ... }
```

This causes a nasty error when trying to generate the WSDL from WCF:

> Could not load type 'Test.Foo' from assembly 'Test, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' because the format is invalid.

I'm doing this to prevent ReSharper from automatically re-ordering elements of my class. I want them to be ordered per the DataMember/MessageBodyMember attribute's Order value.

This is really weird because it works on Data Contracts, just not Message Contracts for some reason.

Comment: What does `StructLayout` have to do with ReSharper at all? It's meant to control layout of members at runtime when marshalling, in either P/Invoke or COM interop scenarios.

Comment: ReSharper sees that attribute and does not reorder members when doing an cleanup of the file. It's the only way I've found to prevent reordering of members explicitly on a per-class basis.

Yeah, it's not really meant for this but I also don't know why it would break WCF's messages. It has worked on everything else I have thrown at it (in WCF and otherwise).